# Are collisions between expressions and namespaces expected when invoking ADL?

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup

Given the following example, I would expect the parser to recognize std as a function:

```
#include <algorithm>

namespace test
{
    class foo{};

    void std(foo f);
}

int main()
{
    std(test::foo());
    return 0;
}
```

However, with GCC 4.8.4 this results in an error - *"error: unexpected namespace name 'std': expected expression."*

With clang 5.0, I get *"error: unexpected namespace name 'std': expected expression"*

Is this expected? I can't imagine that the parser doesn't have enough context here to distinguish between expression and namespace?

EDIT: Example uses more complex type that should invoke ADL. In my actual use case, the code is generic and I require ADL.

Comment: That's not how ADL works. ADL would work if you had e.g. `struct S {};` in `namespace test`, and your function used it as a parameter.

Comment: ADL does not happen if: _...any declaration that is not a function or a function template (e.g. a function object or another variable whose name conflicts with the name of the function that's being looked up)"_ from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl  So it finds the `std` namespace which is not a function and stops.

Answer (score 6):

There's no ADL for `int`.

There's also no ADL if normal unqualified lookup finds, among other things, ["a declaration that is neither a function nor a function template"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lookup.argdep#3.3), such as a declaration of a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work for couple of reasons.

1. It does not use ADL.  ADL will be used if the argument to a function is a type that is defined in the namespace. E.g.

   ```
   namespace test
   {
      struct bar {};

      void foo(bar b) {}
   }

   // uses ADL to resolve to test::foo.
   foo(test::bar());
   ```
2. `std` is a namespace. When used without any other scope qualifier, it is the name of the namespace. Hence ADL won't be used even if you used a type that is defined in the namespace. Hence, the following is not correct either.

   ```
   namespace test
   {
      struct bar {};

      void std(bar b) {}
   }

   std(test::bar());
   ```

Please note that you may use:

```
namespace test
{
   struct bar {};

   void std(bar b) {}
}

test::std(test::bar());
```

Comment: I get all of this. My mistake with using int. That was my attempt to form a minimum example. I still would like clarification on the "why" and not just the "what" for (2). The compiler guys can't possibly argue that I could have wanted namespace std in that context?

Comment: @mgoldman, fair enough. I'll try to look up the why later today.